# Pre-processed images for the CNN?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, histogram, conv-neural-network

There maybe different articles in which they have pre-processed images for the CNN network. I found article that uses mapped LBP images as an input to the CNN. Is it appropriate to use HoG image input to the CNN?

Answer (score 0):

You may well do it: [A combined HOG and deep convolution network cascade for
pedestrian detection](https://www.ingentaconnect.com/contentone/ist/ei/2017/00002017/00000004/art00003?crawler=true&mimetype=application/pdf). In some cases (small amount of data, no pre-training of the network) it can even give you a better accuracy than a CNN on raw pixel values. But otherwise you will probably end up with the same or lower accuracy.

Comment: Thanks for the suggesting the article. I have saw that before but I couldn't understand that the HOG features are 1D features.. did they used 1D CNN for further extraction of features.?

Comment: Why 1D? HoG features provide you with several channels of 2D feature maps. For the SVM input, they are flattened, but you can feed those as 2D image to CNN.

Comment: I am using build-in MATLAB function `[featureVector,hogVisualization] = extractHOGFeatures(img);` the output feature vector is 1D. How I can use 2D HoG image as an input to CNN?

Comment: It's 2D feature vector with the values stored contiguously in a 1D array: https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/extracthogfeatures.html#btxscw9-3